# Error in Python code for Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and this is my first question on stackoverflow so sorry if it's not correct. I am programming my own rock, paper scissors game in Python, which includes a computer class which remembers the previous turn of the player. However, I can only get it to return random.choice moves, and I am not sure where I am going wrong?

```
moves = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_move = None
        self.their_move = None

    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
        self.my_move = my_move
        self.their_move = their_move

def beats(one, two):
    return ((one == 'rock' and two == 'scissors') or
            (one == 'scissors' and two == 'paper') or
            (one == 'paper' and two == 'rock'))

class MemoryPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        if self.their_move in moves:
            return self.their_move
        else:
            return random.choice(moves)

class Game:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.scorep1 = 0
        self.scorep2 = 0
    # starting score of both players

    def play_round(self):
        firstmove = self.p1.move()
        secondmove = self.p2.move()
        print(f"Player 1: {firstmove}  Player 2: {secondmove}")
    # prints move of Player 1 and Player 2 after each round
        if beats(firstmove, secondmove):
            self.scorep1 += 1
            print(f"Player 1 Wins. Score: {self.scorep1}"
                  f" to {self.scorep2}")
        elif beats(secondmove, firstmove):
            self.scorep2 += 1
            print(f"Player 2 Wins. Score: {self.scorep2}"
                  f" to {self.scorep1}")
        else:
            print(f"Boring - TIE. Score: {self.scorep1}"
                  f" to {self.scorep2}")
    # uses beats function in if and else statement to define score increase
    # if player 1 move beats player 2 move and vice versa

    def play_game(self):
        print("Game start!")
        self.rounds = 3
        for round in range(self.rounds):
            print(f"Round {round}:")
            self.play_round()
        print(f"Game over! Final score:\
             Player 1: {self.scorep1}), Player 2: {self.scorep2}")
        # prints final secores for Player 1 and Player 2
        if self.scorep1 > self.scorep2:
            print("Player 1 is Triumphant")
        # if player 1 score is greater than player 2 - prints winning statement
        elif self.scorep2 > self.scorep1:
            print("Player 2 is Triumphant")
        # if player 2 score is greater than player 1 - prints winning statement
        else:
            print("Boring - TIE")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game(HumanPlayer(), MemoryPlayer())
    # randomly chooses opposing NPC
    game.play_game()
```

Comment: You haven't posted a [mcve], so we can only guess at what's going wrong.  Perhaps `self.their_move` is capitalized differently than the elements of `moves`, or some such minor difference.

Comment: I have added more code to provide the background

Comment: You don't appear to ever call `.learn()`, so `self.their_move` never gets assigned a value other than the initial `None`.